# How to get an attribute of an element from Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, getattribute

I'm working with Selenium in Python. I would like to get the `.val()` of a `<select>` element and check that it is what I expect.

This is my code:

```
def test_chart_renders_from_url(self):
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/analyse/'
    self.browser.get(url)
    org = driver.find_element_by_id('org')
    # Find the value of org?
```

How can I do this? The Selenium documentation seem to have plenty about selecting elements but nothing about attributes.

Comment: [selenium-python-docs, 7.11](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement) `get_attribute(name)` might do the job, although I don't think I've actually used it. Give it a shot!

Answer (score 202, accepted):

You are probably looking for `get_attribute()`. An example is shown [here](http://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/api.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) as well

```
def test_chart_renders_from_url(self):
    url = 'http://localhost:8000/analyse/'
    self.browser.get(url)
    org = driver.find_element_by_id('org')
    # Find the value of org?
    val = org.get_attribute("attribute name")
```

Answer (score 77):

**Python**

```
element.get_attribute("attribute name")
```

---

**Java**

```
element.getAttribute("attribute name")
```

---

**Ruby**

```
element.attribute("attribute name")
```

---

**C#**

```
element.GetAttribute("attribute name");
```

Answer (score 11):

As the recent developed *Web Applications* are using [JavaScript](https://www.javascript.com/), [jQuery](https://jquery.com/), [AngularJS](https://angular.io/), [ReactJS](https://reactjs.org/) etc there is a possibility that to retrieve an attribute of an element through *Selenium* you have to induce [WebDriverWait](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.wait.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.wait) to synchronize the *WebDriver* instance with the lagging *Web Client* i.e. the *Web Browser* before trying to retrieve any of the attributes.

Some examples:

- Python:

  - To retrieve any attribute from a ***visible*** element (e.g. *`<h1>`* tag) you need to use the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [visibility_of_element_located(locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.visibility_of_element_located) as follows:

    ```
    attribute_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "org"))).get_attribute("attribute_name")
    ```
  - To retrieve any attribute from an ***interactive*** element (e.g. `<input>` tag) you need to use the [expected_conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#module-selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions) as [element_to_be_clickable(locator)](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_support/selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.html#selenium.webdriver.support.expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable) as follows:

    ```
    attribute_value = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "org"))).get_attribute("attribute_name")
    ```

---

### HTML Attributes

Below is a list of some attributes often used in HTML

[image: HTML Attributes]

**Note**: A complete list of all attributes for each HTML element, is listed in: [HTML Attribute Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_attributes.asp)