# How to get an ID using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I want to obtain a value of an ID in a class. Example:

```
<div class="a_class_name_a" an_identifier="1" id="the_requered_id_like_54656"></div>
<div class="a_class_name_a" an_identifier="2" id="the_requered_id_like_4565"></div>
<div class="a_class_name_a" an_identifier="3" id="the_requered_id_like_12"></div>
<div class="a_class_name_b" an_identifier="4" id="the_requered_id_like_786"></div>
<div class="a_class_name_c" an_identifier="5" id="the_requered_id_like_566"></div>
```

How do I obtain the value "the_requered_id_like_786" of id with  an_identifier="4" as my selection criteria using Selenium Webdriver and Python?

Comment: You could iterate through the div elements and check if elem.get_attribute("an_identifier") == "4" then elem.get_attribute("id") will be  "the_requered_id_like_786"

Comment: Thx. I will try your answer.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do in this way:

```
id= driver.find_element_by_xpath("//div[@class='a_class_name_b' and @an_identifier='4']").get_attribute("id")
print(id)
```

Comment: Thank you. I'm novice regarding Python, still had some issues but your solution finally worked.

Comment: @Luc Happy to help