# Is it possible to get the name of a class in a div while using Selenium + Python

Tags: python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

```
<span id="app_status_health">
 <span class="status_indicator yellow" id="ext-gen10267"></span>
</span>
```

I wanted to know if its possible to get the class name "status_indicator yellow" and store it in a variable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Comment: I saw that and it didn't work for me

Comment: But in accepted answer the same implementation was used!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```
class_name = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#app_status_health>span").get_attribute("class")
```

Hope it helps you!

Comment: @K.Abhulimen, if my answer was helpful -- check a tick near my answer, thanks.