# How to retrieve a element from HTML and XPATH using python?

Tags: html, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I have a HTML as follows:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="jform[groups][]" value="2" id="1group_2" checked="checked" rel="1group_1">
```

I want to get the attribute "checked" from this using selenium webdriver.
How do I do that?

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: How did you try?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

As per the *HTML* you have shared to retrieve the value **checked** from the attribute **checked** you can use:

- `css_selector`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_css_selector("input[id*='group_'][name^='jform'][type='checkbox']").get_attribute("checked")
  ```
- `xpath`:

  ```
  driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[contains(@id,'group_') and starts-with(@name,'jform')][@type='checkbox']").get_attribute("checked")
  ```