# Python Selenium - get custom attribute value

Tags: python-3.x, selenium

I have a folloving HTML code:

```html
<option value="789444" sample="" sample_custom_attribute="SCA" selected="">Sand Box</option>
```

Is there a whey to get custom attribute value from this one with selenium. I wanna get value from sample_custom_attribute ("SCA").

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Once you locate the element it it is a matter of using

```
element.get_attribute('sample_custom_attribute')
```

Comment: @timmy It doesn't

Comment: it does work on soup objects right(i.e when there is an equal sign '=' )

Comment: @timmy Yes, it works like that on soup, `element['sample_custom_attribute']` will return `[u'SCA']`