# Selenium xpath with multiple conditions and fetch element value

Tags: selenium, xpath

I have a condition where tr row which generates dynamic value:

```
<tbody>
   <tr id="24686" tabindex="0">
     <td class="nowrap xh-highlight" style="padding: 3px 8px;">Available</td>
   </tr>
</tbody>
```

I have Xpath 1: (//tbody/tr/td[contains(text(),'Available')])[1] which returns

```
Available
```

and Xpath 2: //tr[1]/@id which returns

```
ld_9050427
22707
```

The condition is that I want to generate one xpath which will return first number whose status is Available and then return its ID. Later on I want to use this same id to carry on later process?

I tried something like below but it didn't work

```
(//tbody/tr[/@id and/td[contains(text(),'Disponible')]])[1]
```

Comment: What is your exact desired output? Do you want to select table row by `@id` and the text value of child `td`?

Comment: @Andersson Id is something that is generated dynamically and I have three status Available, In Progress, Not Available. I want to select first unit that has status Available and then fetch its dynamic ID which is present in tr row.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to select `tr` that has `id` attribute (any) and table cell with text `"Available"` try

```
//tr[@id and td='Available']
```

to extract `id` value for further use you need [`get_attribute`/`getAttribute` method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

To find the first number whose status is **Available** and then return its ID you can use the following solution:

- *xpath*:

  ```
  "//tbody//tr//td[text()='Available']/.."
  ```

Note 1: The `..` in the *xpath* refers to the ancestor node

Note 2: As you are looking for the first match with the implemented condition, you have use either:

- Python:

  ```
  find_element_by_xpath()
  ```
- Java:

  ```
  findElement()
  ```
- C#:

  ```
  FindElement()
  ```

Note 3: Finally you have to use [getAttribute("id")](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) / [get_attribute("id")](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) to extract the value of the `id` attribute as follows:

Comment: I am looking for something like this (//tbody/tr[/@id and/td[contains(text(),'Availabel')]])[1]

Comment: @PranjalPrakashSrivastava As you mentioned _...and then return its ID..._ so your end target is the `<tr>` from where you have to extract the ID e.g. **24686**. Then why would you at all trying to land within the `<td>`?

Comment: <td> is the child which has different status. There are three status Available, In Progress and Not Available. So I want to select first unit whose status is Available and then fetch its id so that I can use its ID for further use.

Comment: That is what I spoke about in my ans. However you never mentioned the _language binding_ you are using. You have to use `find_element_by_xpath()`