# Get Text from specific tag in Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

I would like to get the text inside this specific element here

```
<div class="comment-text-inner display-inline" data-clipboard-text="free apex coins">free apex coins</div>
```

How do I get the text from "data-clipboard-text" using python and selenium?

I've tried

```
comment = driver.find_element_by_xpath("""/html/body/div[3]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[4]/div[2]/div/div[1]""").text
```

With no luck

Comment: That xpath depends on the entire document structure, which you haven't shown us, so we don't know why it isn't working.

Comment: Well, i get the same output if I use the classname "comment-text-inner"

Comment: What the comment variable consists of after this line is "loading". Which isn't anywhere in the element.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 3):

I think you're looking for the method `get_attribute()`.

Essentially, it'd be something like:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath(<your xpath>).get_attribute("data-clipboard-text")
```

Please see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium) as well.

Comment: He said he wanted the text.  I don't think he wants the attribute value (though in this example they are the same).

Comment: His question specifically states _How do I get the text from "data-clipboard-text" using python and selenium?_