# How to get href text from 'a' tag with selenium

Tags: python, pandas, selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page.. But the link I need is in an href in an 'a' tag.
how can I get it with selenium (or BS4)

my code..

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
import pyautogui as ptg 

PATH = "C:\Program Files (x86)\chromedriver.exe"
SRC = requests.get("Link (hidden for security)").text
SOUP = BeautifulSoup(SRC, 'lxml')

driver = webdriver.Chrome(PATH)
driver.get("Link (hidden for security)")
#driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,1500)")

email = "(Hidden for security)"
password = "(Hidden for security)"

log_in_btn_1 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/div[2]/a[2]").click()
#email_input_btn = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div[2]/form/ul/li[1]/input").click()


#Point(x=325, y=234) // email coords
#Point(x=588, y=303) // pass coords
ptg.click(325, 234)
ptg.typewrite(email, interval=0.05)
ptg.click(588, 303)
ptg.typewrite(password, interval=0.05)

log_in_btn_2 = driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/div/div/div[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td/div[3]/div[2]/form/ul/li[3]/input").click()

#Point(x=1188, y=59) // URL area

post_link = "(hidden for security)"

ptg.click(537, 75)
ptg.typewrite(post_link)
ptg.typewrite(["enter"])
```

---

> The links are hidden for security purposes

---

please help.

Comment: like for example, <a href="The text that I want">Dumb text</a>

Comment: with `.get_attribute()`, cf the documentation: https://www.browserstack.com/guide/getattribute-method-in-selenium

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Comment: I will try and test it now

Comment: It can't, I am using python and the website you're referencing to is using java

Comment: @RazerPYOfficial what part is not working? The `.get_attribute()` or the original question I linked (yours is a duplicate)?

Answer (score 0):

From https://code.luasoftware.com/tutorials/selenium/get-href-of-element-with-selenium-python/:

```
el = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("a.link")
if el:
    url = el.get_attribute("href")
```