# Python Selenium identifying xpath iframes element

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, iframe, element

I am trying to find the names of all iframes in a web page. When I run `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe")` I get `session="f139d552bcf5b17598ba7b5af3987c8", element="04036644-d6cf-40a1-9434-5ce5d951e9a"` how do I correlate this back to a name that is useful in html so that I can switch by different locators like tag, css, id, etc.? Preferably not in Java but if that is the only solution available that's fine. What kind of Id /attribute is element="04036644-d6cf-40a1-9434-5ce5d951e9a". Can someone provide an example of what the code would look like?

Comment: you can return the attribute of the iframe element using get_Attribute() method. In this case, you can return the tag, id , class or any attribute value on the element.

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//iframe").get_attribute("name"), get_attribute("id") etc.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Comment: Do you have an example of what the code snippet would look like and what the expected result would be?

Comment: This example helped me thank you very much