# Getting attribute's content with xPath

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-ide

I want to get the attribute's content with this xPath command

`"//*[@id="navbarleft"]/div[1]/ul[3]/li[2]/@class"`

but it seems like it return the object attribute `@class` rather than it's content:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

Use string function. add your xpath in string function

```
string(//*[@id='navbarleft']/div[1]/ul[3]/li[2]/@class)
```