# Using Selenium Python to get "data-label" attribute

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I've a table who regroups multiple `data-label` with multiple names , I tried to use `driver.get_elements_by_css_selector` method but it didn't work , here's the HTML that I wanna get values from:

```
<tbody>
 <tr>
   <td data-label="Player">Pierre-Emerick Aubameyang</td>
   <td data-label="Gross Weekly Wages">£250,000</td>
  </tr>
 <tr>
   <td data-label="Player">Willian</td>
   <td data-label="Gross Weekly Wages">£195,000</td>
 </tr>
  .
  .
  .
</tbody>
```

Since I'm having a lot of `tr` where each one has player information , I did this code but it's not working.

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
        for element in elements:
            player_info = element.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
            player_name = player_info[0].get_attribute('data-label')
            player_week_salary = player_info[1].get_attribute('data-label')
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Comment: I tired that but It didnt work  , I didn't know how can I refer to the `data-label` , since I call it as a tag attribute but didn't provide me any information.

Comment: If you've tried that, you should include your code in your question, so we can help you fix it.

Comment: @MikeScotty sorry , I'm new here , yes I added that now , you can check sir. thank you

Comment: @testing01 try to use better:
elements = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//tr/td')
for el in elements:
     print(el.get_attribute('data-label'))

Comment: @testing01 : is that only html you have?? Can post the entire table HTML?

Comment: I did that , thank you for your help sir

Comment: @testing01 : What error are you getting? while printing those value?

Comment: it gets me an empty list

Comment: `player_name = player_info[0].get_attribute('data-label')`
`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: @testing01 : I believe you want to get the players name and weekly wages?? in that case  `print[ name.text for name in  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//td[@data-label="Player"]')]` and  `print[ wages.text for wages in  driver.find_elements(By.XPATH , '//td[@data-label="Gross Weekly Wages"]')]`

Answer (score 1):

to get data by attribute in selenium, use method:

```
element.get_attribute('you_attribute')
```

for that example it should look like it:

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')
attr = elements[0].get_attribute('data-label')
print(attr)
```

or use already answered questions by link:
[How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Comment: It seems like he has a problem with identifying locators.

Comment: I tried some modification on my code i'll add that to my original post , so I'm trying to get all informations.

Comment: @testing01 of course if you need to get all of the tr's data-labels, you can run the loop with elements like:
for el in elements:
  print(el.get_attribute('data-label'))
i just provided example

Comment: Vova, good point. Then you can use find_elements_by_xpath or find_elements_by_css_selector to put all your data in a list.

Answer (score 0):

You need to correctly identify your locator.
In your case XPATH locator is: `//tr/td[1]`

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[1]")
```

And

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[2]")
```

for the second element and so on.

You can also use CSS selectors. Read about `nth-of-type(1)` to identify similar locators.
For taking attribute use `get_attribute` method.
Try:

```
locator = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//tr/td[1]")
your_attribute = locator.get_attribute("data-label")
```

Or use `td:nth-of-type(1)`, `td: nth-of-type(2)` and so on as CSS locators. It will look like this:

```
driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td:nth-of-type(1)").get_attribute("data-label")
```

Answer (score 0):

To get the elements by xpath you'd have to . to the child element.

```
elements = driver.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')
    for element in elements:
        player_name = element.find_element_by_xpath("./td[1]").get_attribute('data-label')
        player_week_salary = element.find_element_by_xpath("./td[2]").get_attribute('data-label')
        print(player_name,player_week_salary)
```