# How to get id value and "parid" value using Selenenim

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm working with Selenium in Python. I want to extract all `id` and `parid` values (I don't even know what `parid` means).

```
<li class="left_nav-li child" id="7012" onclick="getProductsFromCategory(this)" parid="7011">xxx<div class="submenu"></div></li>
```

I have a lot of this kind of element.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use get_attribute: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/get_attribute-element-method-selenium-python/

```
element.get_attribute("attribute name")
```