# Having trouble copying using python selenium

Tags: python, selenium

When I use the inspector tool, It says that the element is an input box. I am not sure how to work around it as I'm very inexperienced with python

```
from selenium import selenium webdriver

Emailsite = webdriver.Chrome(Folder + '\chromedriver.exe')
Emailsite.get('https://10minutemail.com/')
time.sleep(2)
print(Emailsite.find_element_by_id('mail_address').text)
```

The output is an empty string despite the website displaying an email for me to use.

Answer (score 2):

The email address is stored in the value of the input field.

```
print(Emailsite.find_element_by_id('mail_address').get_attribute('value'))
```

As per [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)