# Python-Selenium: How to get the element href value?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, css-selectors, webdriverwait

I am using python selenium and trying to get the email listed below:

```
 <a class="contactAction-214" aria-label="Email example@example.com" tabindex="0" draggable="false" href="mailto:example@example.com"><i data-icon-name="Mail" aria-hidden="true" class="icon-224"></i><span class="text-219"><span>example@example.com</span></span></a>
```

I am trying to get the email: example@example.com above;
I have been stuck on this for about an hour now and I think the easiest way to do this would be to get the href or aria-label, any help appriceated!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 0):

You could try it like this. You first find the Xpath to the particular part of the HTML you are looking for and then you ask for the aria-label attribute

```
email = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[@class='contactAction-214']").get_attribute("aria-label")
```

Answer (score 0):

To print the text *`example@example.com`* you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `css_selector` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class^='contactAction'][aria-label^='Email'][href] span[class] > span").get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- Using `xpath` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@class, 'contactAction') and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Email')][@href]//span[@class]/span").text)
  ```

---

Ideally you need to induce [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49775502/webdriverwait-not-working-as-expected/49775808#49775808) for the [*visibility_of_element_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50468629/python-selenium-wait-until-element-is-fully-loaded/50474905#50474905) and you can use either of the following [Locator Strategies](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver/48376890#48376890):

- Using `CSS_SELECTOR` and *text* attribute:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "a[class^='contactAction'][aria-label^='Email'][href] span[class] > span"))).text)
  ```
- Using `XPATH` and `get_attribute("innerHTML")`:

  ```
  print(WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//a[starts-with(@class, 'contactAction') and starts-with(@aria-label, 'Email')][@href]//span[@class]/span"))).get_attribute("innerHTML"))
  ```
- **Note** : You have to add the following imports :

  ```
  from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
  from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
  from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
  ```

> You can find a relevant discussion in [How to retrieve the text of a WebElement using Selenium - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55240245/how-to-retrieve-the-text-of-a-webelement-using-selenium-python/55241232#55241232)

---

### References

Link to useful documentation:

- [`get_attribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.get_attribute) method `Gets the given attribute or property of the element.`
- [`text`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webelement.WebElement.text) attribute returns `The text of the element.`
- [Difference between text and innerHTML using Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40416048/difference-between-text-and-innerhtml-using-selenium/55902072#55902072)