# Python Selenium - Xpatch should be an element

Tags: python, selenium, xpath

I have this in my code:

```
link_tag = "//div[@class= 'yuRUbf']//a/@href"
```

With this code I get this error

```
The result of the xpath expression "//div[@class= 'yuRUbf']//a/@href" is: [object Attr]. It should be an element.
```

I don't know any other way to scrape the URL from that div class. How can I fix this?
This code works fie on the scraper chrome extension but not on python.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get attribute of element from Selenium?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to change your XPath to select an element node (as the error message suggests) - and not an attribute node - and, after that, get its attribute. So use

```
link_tag = "//div[@class= 'yuRUbf']//a"
links = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(link_tag)
```

and then extract the attribute with

```
links[0].get_attribute("href")
```

to get the `@href` attribute of the first matching element.

Answer (score 0):

This solution might work.

```
div = driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,"div[class='yuRUbf']")
url = div.get_attribute("href")
```