# Selenium Python how to read characteristics from a DIV?

Tags: python, selenium

i have the following div:

```
<div 
data-qa="posting house" data-id="25364875" data-to-posting="25364875_pos" 
class="sc-Xml_house"> ... 
<div>
```

How can I read the value of the label: "data-to-posting"

thanks

Comment: Use get_attibute() method of the webelement: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium

Comment: @BarrythePlatipus this is link 
https://urbania.pe/buscar/venta-de-departamentos-en-villa-maria-del-triunfo--lima--lima?currencyId=6
thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `WebDriverWait` and `visibility_of_element_located`:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By #make sure to add this import 

from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

elem = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.sc-Xml_house'))).get_attribute("data-to-posting")

# visibility_of_element_located --> waiting until an element is present on the DOM of a page and visible
```

Comment: thanks thanks but it gives me this error: 
NameError: name 'By' is not defined

Comment: you need an additional import, i updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

First identify the element and then get_attribute()

```
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//div[data-qa="posting house"]').get_attribute("data-to-posting")
```

Comment: thanks thanks but it gives me this error:
NameError: name 'By' is not defined