# How can I find reference to a specific element in a list that changes in length regularly using python and selenium for a webscraper

Tags: python, selenium

I'm very new a web scraping and have hit a issue with being able to check to see if I have reached a specific element in a list. The list changes length regularly, so I have been trying to check for the text/label of the element in the list, but the code I have tried has not worked.

Once the element "M" has been reached I want to exit the loop.

[image]

I have tried using the X-path, but the element number changes, last week it was:
/html/body/ul/li[292]/div

this week it is [293], but the number will be changing often.

I have tried different approaches, my last one was using the class name "group"

```
element.driver.find_elements_by_class_name("group")
```

Any help or direction to any resources that may help are greatly appreciated!

Comment: Well, how do YOU know where the element is today? Whatever criteria that you, human (presumably) is using to track it, you can make the scraper to do.

Comment: Can you confirm the url, is it publicly accessible?

Comment: It's a website used for my job, stores currently open are on the list, but if they're temporarily closed they drop off the list. I can iterate through them using the xpath, but I'm just not sure how to approach the synatx to check the class name of the link to see if I'm in the "group" class

Comment: You would need to provide some of your actual code, and what is the error you are currently getting

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath to loop through the list of `li` elements.

xpath = `//li[@role='menuitem'][@class='ui-menu-item']/div`

Then check for `class` attribute and validate if it contains `entity-selected`.

You can look for how to do this at [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30324760/how-to-get-attribute-of-element-from-selenium).

When found the element, use the `[getText]` to fetch the text contained in it. Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20996392/how-to-get-text-with-selenium-webdriver-in-python).